# How to increase Chart Title and axis scale values and Title in any chart in Anylogic

Tags: charts, fonts, anylogic

In AnyLogic, The **Chart title and Axis Scale values & Title** are very small, Audience are not able to see in these scale values and title in presentation, We have to again redraw all charts in excel with the data provided by AnyLogic, Its a rework.  Please give a **feature to increase their font** in AnyLogic chart.

[Image of Chart in AnyLogic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i43xU.png)

Comment: Thank you, but what exactly is the question? Do you want a workaround for this limitation?

Comment: Yes , give a feature to increase font, change color of font of **Title and axis scale values in Title** of charts in AnyLogic, this feature is very much needed. The same kind of feature is available in Statistica Analytical tool

Comment: I realize that you posted your question as a feature request for AnyLogic, but as Ben said it is very unlikely that they will spend development time on that. I hope my answer provides you a suitable workaround. Let me know!

Comment: Yes, This was a feature request for Anylogic, But This small feature can reduce rework and we can directly paste Anylogic charts to presentation,

Comment: Was my answer not a suitable solution to your question?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way to do this yourself and have full control over the chart you can create the following: The top is custom labels for the axis and the bottom is the standard AnyLogic chart

[image]

Start by disabling the Y and X-axis

[image]

Unfortunately this also removes the lines so you will need to add these yourself.

Now you are free to create your own text objects, place them where you want to, change the color, font etc.

For dates, you can also use your own date formatter

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. But you can always reduce the size of your chart (relative to the font size) and then use a view area to zoom into the chart to make the fonts look good. Not ideal but possible.

Alternatively, use the Cloud capabilities with responsive charts.

For feature requests, you should best email to support@anylogic.com.

But given that they will launch AnyLogic 9 with a completely revamped UI soon, this will likely not make it for AL8 :)